# MFC SDI Text Editor

Tags: mfc, textedit, sdi

I am creating an MFC SDI explorer style application (it has a splitter bar and the right-hand pane is the text-edit area, left-hand pane is the tree-view)

My right-hand pane is a CRichEditView.

I want to be able to detect when a user has edited the text so that a flag is set to show that a change has been made but has not been saved. I have tried several ways of doing this e.g. catching WM_KEYDOWN in PreTranslateMessage, but this catches everything and prevents the keypresses from editing the view. I have also tried adding ON_WM_KEYDOWN() to the message map in the MyView.cpp. Again, this seems to prevent the keystrokes from having any affect on the text in the view. I want to allow the user to edit the text in the view, but the application to know that this has been done.

Please help - I have looked for hours for ways to do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding ON_WM_KEYDOWN() to the message map is probably the correct approach. You must make sure that your implementation of the OnKeyDown() method calls the base class method so that the message gets passed on as appropriate.

Comment: ah yes, I first tried pWnd->OnKeyDown() which caused compile errors, but then tried CWnd::OnKeyDown which worked.

Comment: many thanks for your help. Do you know why CWnd::OnKeyDown() worked but pWnd->OnKeyDown() didn't?